# Java 8 HashMap KeySet() output different from Java 7

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8

I upgraded from Java 7 to Java 8 and noticed Junit failures in places where the keySet() of HashMap was used.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("var1".toUpperCase(), "var");
map.put("var".toUpperCase(), "var1");
Set<String> varKeys = replacementMap.keySet();
```

In Java 7:

```
varKeys=[VAR,VAR1]
```

In Java 8:

```
varKeys=[VAR1,VAR]
```

Any help on this?

Comment: `Set` and `Map` are unorderer collections by definition. The output is correct in both cases.

Comment: What is the JUNIT test case you have written ? The order is not guaranteed in a HashMap/Set , You can try a TreeSet if order needs to be guaranteed.

Comment: `"var1".toUpperCase()` should be `VAR1` not `var1`

Answer (score 15):

`HashMap` does not guarentee order of keys. If your Junit test relied on the order of keys, then it is designed incorrectly.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using `LinkedHashMap` instead if you want to preserve insertion order.

The order of `HashMap` isn't defined and isn't consistent. i.e. the same keys can appear in different orders. The implementation of HashMap changed between Java 7 and Java 8 significantly so you should expect the order to be different in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

`Set` doesn't guarantee order of elements. If you need ordered hashmap, you can use `LinkedHashMap`

Answer (score 3):

That's a HashSet/HashMap, where order is never guaranteed and can change at any time. What you want is [TreeSet or LinkedHashSet](https://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/hashset-vs-treeset-vs-linkedhashset/), learn here about differences.